# How to implement a shared notification queue between Symfony3 and Android app?

Tags: php, android, symfony, firebase, push-notification

I'm currently developing a Symfony web project that needs to show notifications like Facebook does.

In the future, this project will provide an REST API for connect Android/iOS apps and send push notifications.

So the question is: What is the best option to store notifications on Symfony, that will be shared to other devices in the future? I need to keep consistency, if a user receive a notification on the mobile, he must receive it in the web also. If I delete a notification on the web, it must automatically disapear from the mobile, and so on.

My first approach was to create a simple Symfony Entity to store on DB all the notifications, and when I need to send any notification I can store the notification on the DB (to show it on the web) and also, send the notification via FCM (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=es-419). But maybe is better to have a unique shared queue.

What do you think?